What is this locking arm part of a hinge called?

Just the locking arm, not the whole bracket.
I'm trying to buy or make one but they seem to have gone out of style.  Now everyone uses and sells a different mechanism with a sliding quick release that has about 10 parts and takes a lot of space.
Here is another example


“Locking strut” got lots of hydraulic, but also this: https://us.rs-online.com/product/camloc/005520-10/71104121

see https://www.amazon.com/s?k=lid+stay, for example. BTW, I can understand that they're not too popular -- having pinched fingers in 'em. ;-)

Oo that telescopic stay is cute and surprisingly not expensive.  Wrong geometry for what I'm doing now but I'll have to find a project for it.  :)

@DrMoishePippik I agree. There are better solutions.  I added flaps to the sides of a home-made rolling cart, using leftover bits of plywood and leftover hinges.  $0 cost.  I don't want to spend $20 per flap for hardware.    I could make them out of wood but it's fidgety and still needs hardware.  Lid Stays it is.   These things are cheap and strong.

"Folding support" and "folding lid stay" gets me some hits on search pages for the simple folding metal part.
You'll have to shop around, quite a few results incorporate a soft close in there as well.
